# Python function argument used as a function call in the return statement?

Tags: python, function, return

So I've come across the code below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104087/calculating-with-functions-codewars-problem/64976913#64976913), and I can't wrap my head around how the return statements work. `operation` is an argument in the functions `seven` and `five` but it's used as a function call in the `return` statements. What's happening here?

The code is :

```
def seven(operation = None):
    if operation == None:
        return 7
    else:
        return operation(7)


def five(operation = None):
    if operation == None:
        return 5
    else:
        return operation(5)


def times(number):
   return lambda y: y * number
```

Edit: following @chepner comment this is how they are called, for example this:

```
print(seven(times(five())))
```

Comment: In python functions can be passed to other functions as argument as they are so called **first-class citizens**. See here: [What is first class function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392402/what-is-first-class-function-in-python)

Comment: You are missing how `seven` and `five` get *called*. For example, you might write `seven(times)`, which would return a function that multiplies *its* argument by `7`. Then `seven(times)(3) == 21`.

Comment: You see this a lot in functional programming: `times` is a function that partially applies the `*` operator to its argument. `times(3) == lambda y: y * 3`. You can also write `times(3)(7) == 21`. `five` and `seven` are functions that apply their arguments to `5` and `7`, respectively.

Comment: The default argument `None` in both is standing in for the identity function, `lambda x : x`. It would be very nice if this were built-in to Python under the name `id`, but (alas) that name is already taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those methods are basically allowing you to pass function objects which will be called. See this example

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

def five(operation=None):
    if operation is None:
        return 5
    else:
        return operation(5)
```

I can now call `five` and pass `square` as the `operation`

```
>>> five(square)
25
```

Answer (score 0):

*What's happening here?*

This code utilize that functions are *first-class citizens* in `python`, therefore functions might be passed as functions arguments. This ability is not unique to `python` language, but might be initally mind-boggling if you are accustomed to language without that feature.